# PHP. Как реализовать чтение из CSV для скрипта?

Tags: php, html

Добрый день.
Имеется простенький чат+бот на php.
Но он пробегается по заданному в скрипте блоку фраза+ответ:

```
$responses['what is your name'] = "My name is Mo-Pal.";
  $responses['tell me about yourself'] = "I am a chatbot. I'm still learning a lot of things so please forgive me if I can't answer you in some cases.";
  $responses["i'm fine"] = "Good. I'm happy about that.";
```

Хотелось бы реализовать чтение из csv файла.
Допустим чтобы в csv было 2 стобца. Столбец того что пишем боту и столбец того что отвечает бот.

Код скрипта:

```
<?php 
  $responses['what is your name'] = "My name is Mo-Pal.";
  $responses['tell me about yourself'] = "I am a chatbot. I'm still learning a lot of things so please forgive me if I can't answer you in some cases.";
  $responses["i'm fine"] = "Good. I'm happy about that.";
  $q = $_GET["q"];

  $response = "";

  if ($q != "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    foreach ($responses as $r => $value) {
      if (strpos($r, $q) !== false) {
        $response = $value;
      }

    }
  }
  $noresponse = "Sorry I'm still learning. Hence my responses are limited. Ask something else.";
  echo $response === "" ? $noresponse : $response;
?>
```

Есть идеи товарищи знатоки? В PHP пока новичок :(
Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Функция str_getcsv, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

```
<?php

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));

?>
```

Comment: если файл будет большой - этот вариант будет очень медленным - правильным решением будет читать по строчно, через `fgets`.

Comment: Тогда уж поблочно чтобы ради каждой строки не слать запрос на чтение